# header("Location: ".$url) having troubles with long urls

Tags: php, redirect, header, steam

I am working on a website and am using the steam openid, so far no problems.
The issue is that when I'm trying to redirect the user to the steam openid page it does not work and redirects them to the root of *steamcommunity.com*.

Here is the code:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['steamid']) && $_GET['a'] == "login") {
    $url = SteamSignIn::genUrl($_AMCFG['login_dir']);
    print($url);
    header("Location: ".$url);
}
```

The generated url works perfectly when entered manually but the redirect as I said, not so well.
I tried to manually replace $url in the header and it works fine.

```
header('Location: https://steamcommunity.com/openid/login?openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.return_to=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fadminmailer%2Findex.php&openid.realm=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select');
```

I am very confused as to why this isn't working as expected.

As a temporary fix I have added this to the head:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['a'])) {
        if (!isset($_SESSION['steamid']) && $_GET['a'] == "login") {
            $url = SteamSignIn::genUrl($_AMCFG['login_dir']);
            ?><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=<?php print($url); ?>" /><?php
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Well, what does "not so well" mean? What happens? Have you checked that it's not Steam's end redirecting you?

Comment: You shouldn't print before changing the header

Comment: As I said it redirects me to the root of steamcommunity.com without /openid...

Comment: As said by Apul, you can't print anything before sending headers. But also, have you checked with a debugger like FireBug that the header is being sent, and that you're being redirected or not? I think that Steam is redirecting you to the home, and that your redirect succeed.

Comment: What would I check with FireBug? I'm am still rather new to PHP/HTML, this is my first project.

Answer (score 3):

Don't print anything before `header` redirect.  **[Read Doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)**

It is possible that redirect is being done at correct place but after that you again being redirected to home page i.e. `https://steamcommunity.com`

Comment: The print is here for debug purposes, even without it I still have the same issue. Why would steam be redirecting me if when I use the generated url it works fine, it has to be the header not interpreting the url correctly which is weird since when I manually add it it works fine.